# iccube widget export with header

Tags: iccube-reporting

I try to use the export function in iccube reporting to .png file. The export will come without the widget header and I'm searching for a way to include this.

A second question would be how to automize this by e.g. getting all widgets within a report exported to .png

Comment: not really unless you add the header to the amchart widget. Not sure to understand the second question, do you want a zip with all png's ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. would it be easy to add the header to the amchart widget. I fear I don't know how this is done. A zip with all png's would be a good option. Would this be possible somehow?

Comment: probably, it's a change request that you need to request through the standard channel